# Fixed Area openXml

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I create a excel file with multiple sheets that are copies from a template sheet. I understand that there aren't multiple views allowed. So I clean them:

```
static void CleanView(WorksheetPart worksheetPart)
{
//There can only be one sheet that has focus
SheetViews views = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetViews>();
if (views != null)
{
views.Remove();
worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
}
}
```

But this causes the fixed areas of my sheets to disappear. (Contents of the first 5 rows should not scroll)

When I do not remove the views as listed above, the fixed area from my template work for all sheets but there are weird side-effects (changes made on sheet 1 are also saved on sheet 2, etc.)

How can I create a valid openXML-Document but still use fixed areas?

Comment: have you tried to analyse your excel sheet with productivity tool ?

Comment: The tool cannot open the file. But this should not matter, cause what I see is the expected behaviour. I just want to know what the code is to use ONE View per Sheet

Comment: strange, tool should be able to open the file [hope it's .XLSX file]. Using the tool you can analyse the file as well as get the CODE . That's why I mentioned it :)